# Symbol referenced not foud Qt Creator->android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm porting an application written in Qt 5.9 to android with Qt Creator.
My problem is that when the application is starting I have the following error:

```
failed: cannot locate symbol _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev referenced by libcryptopp_shared.so'
W/System.err(29367): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
W/System.err(29367):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(29367):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err(29367):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.loadApplication(QtLoader.java:237)
W/System.err(29367):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.startApp(QtLoader.java:647)
W/System.err(29367):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivityLoader.onCreate(QtActivityLoader.java:181)
W/System.err(29367):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:269)
W/System.err(29367):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
W/System.err(29367):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
W/System.err(29367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
W/System.err(29367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
W/System.err(29367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
W/System.err(29367):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
W/System.err(29367):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err(29367):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
W/System.err(29367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
W/System.err(29367):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(29367):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err(29367):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
W/System.err(29367):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
W/System.err(29367): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev" referenced by "libcryptopp_shared.so"...
W/System.err(29367):    at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:331)
W/System.err(29367):    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:981)
W/System.err(29367):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative.loadQtLibraries(QtNative.java:171)
W/System.err(29367):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate.loadApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java:502)
W/System.err(29367):    ... 19 more
```

With c++filt -n _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
I obtain:

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
```

I don't understand how to resolve it.
p.s. the project is compiled with qmake

Thank you very much